# DB2: How do I find if a column is present in a table or list of tables?

Tags: sql, db2

Im using a DB2 Database. What would be a suitable SQL query to find out if a column is exists in a table or list of tables?

e.g

```
if "column_name" is found in "table name" or [list of table names]

return true or the name of tables that have that column.
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`SYSCAT.COLUMNS` catalog view](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0001038.htm):

```
SELECT TABNAME
FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABNAME IN ('table name 1', 'table name 2') AND 
    COLNAME = 'column_name';
```

Answer (score 8):

Tested on DB2 z/OS 9.1 and LUW 9.7:

```
SELECT STRIP(TBCREATOR) || '.' || STRIP(TBNAME)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS 
WHERE NAME = 'your_col'
  AND TBNAME IN ('list', 'of', 'tables')
```

If you only want results from a specific schema you might add `AND TBCREATOR = 'your_schema'` to the end of the query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do want to check against tables from a specific Schema. I tried adding the line you suggested but the quest returns nothing (I gave it the name of a column that I know exists).

Can you please explain to me a little bit more how the query works? 

Thanks

Comment: Sorry typo: quest is *request

Comment: What may be messing you up is that you don't add the schema to the `TBNAME` part of the where clause.  Say, for example, you're looking for a column called `UPDATE_TIMESTAMP` that might be in `SCH.TAB1` or `SCH.TAB2`, and you think it may be in `SCH.TAB3` (but it's not).  Your query would be `SELECT STRIP(TBCREATOR) || '.' || STRIP(TBNAME)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS 
WHERE NAME = 'UPDATE_TIMESTAMP'
  AND TBNAME IN ('TAB1', 'TAB2', 'TAB3')
  AND TBCREATOR = 'SCH'`

Comment: And the query would return the table names formatted like SCHEMA.TABLENAME:   `SCH.TAB1` and `SCH.TAB2`  (`SCH.TAB3` is not returned because the column is not in that table).  The `STRIP` part just removes whitespace, otherwise you'd get something like '`SCH     .TAB1`'

Comment: If you need to search in tables for multiple schema, just change the equality to an `IN` comparison.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is with error handling:

```
declare v_sql varchar(1000);
declare col_missing integer default 0;
declare col_does_not_exist condition for sqlstate '42703';
declare continue handler for col_does_not_exist set col_missing = 1;

set v_sql = 'select table.foo from table';
execute immediate v_sql;

if col_missing = 1 then
    --Do something if column foo doesn't exist.
end if;
```

This method will work on session tables, and you can also use it on an object even if you don't know whether it is a table, view, alias, etc.

It is important to specify `table.foo` rather than just the column name, as otherwise the existence of another object (such as a variable) called `foo` would break the test.

This continue handler will mask any other errors for columns missing within the scope, so it is best to limit the scope to just the test you want to do.